# Set Apache2 to process .html files as php 8.0

Tags: php, apache, php-8

I have setup php/apache according to this linode guide: https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/install-php-8-for-apache-and-nginx-on-ubuntu/

This seems to have worked, and I have an apache server that can serve files, and process `.php` files.

However, I am having the darndest time figuring out how to tell apache to process .html files with `.php`. Any modification I make to `.htaccess` (a-la- https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2492/Parse-HTML-As-PHP-Using-HTACCESS-File.html and similar) produce no change. I have also set `AllowOverride All` to the `/var/www/` directory in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Additionally, most online information on the subject points to earlier versions of `.php`, with no specific reference to `8.0`.

What can get apache to process `.html` with `php` `8.0`?

Comment: Why? If the file really is just HTML then PHP won't do anything with it and just send it to the browser. If it's got PHP content, rename it.

Comment: the real answer for me is to help separate front-end pages and back-end library-type code. But isn't this a common enough pattern?

Comment: It's not something I've ever found a need for, and it's not portable. If you start including PHP code in an HTML file you won't be able to port it to any other server without going through this malarkey first, and any other server might not support (or allow) the configuration changes you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have module for this, confirm you have this line in httpd.conf, or add it there:

```
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
```

Also check if you have the `modules/mod_mime.so` file present on your system.

Then find or add module section in httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    # following line will change mime type of .html file to php
    # and they will be handled as such
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</IfModule>
```

Directive `AllowOverride All` will enable .htaccess files but you need the mime_module enabled too.

And of course restart the apache server after making configuration changes.

Module documentation: [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html)

Comment: Thanks!
For others in my shoes, `httpd.conf` doesn't exist, `apache2.conf` was the file I modified. Also, the `<IfModule...` also works fine in the `.htaccess` of the website fine.

Comment: @Snappawapa `httpd.conf` is for user config, the `apache2.conf` should not be modified becuase you can loose your config while upgrading apache. Or at least it was like that, not sure if that changed.

Comment: Good to know, where should `httpd.conf` go then? I can't find it anywhere on my system

Comment: @Snappawapa at `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or take a look inside the `apache2.conf` and search for text "httpd.conf" there should be `Include` directive.

Comment: Nope, doesn't exist. Also no explicit reference in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` But looks like I could probably put it in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`

Comment: @Snappawapa looks like you have debian, https://sources.debian.org/src/apache2/2.4.10-10/debian/config-dir/apache2.conf/ second paragraph and bit further talks about these things

Comment: This helped me, thank you. For future readers, consolidated instructions on Debian: (1) `sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/httpd.conf`. (2) Add the `LoadModule ...` line as well as the `<IfModule> ...` code block, save and quit. (3) Restart Apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`.